# Translating Entity Framework model navigation properties into DTOs

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-5, dto

I’m currently working on an  n-tier web project. After researching into Data Transfer Objects and their benefits we decided to give this pattern a go. Our ASP.NET MVC website does not have direct access to the EF DbContext but instead will use DTOs to send and receive entity data. There will be a service/mapping layer that will convert between DTOs and entity models.

My question is, what is the best way to translate entity model navigation properties into its DTO?

Below is an example of a entity model and its DTO from the project:

**Entity Model:**

```
public class Payment
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PaidOn { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual PaymentMechanism PaymentMechanism { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<Order> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

**DTO:**

```
public class PaymentDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PaidOn { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    //--------Navigation Properties - Object Ids--------
    public int PaymentMechanismId { get; set; }
    public ICollection<int> OrderIds { get; set; }
}
```

As can be seen they are very similar except for the navigation properties. I have changed them to hold integer Ids (of the entities) instead of the entity models. Therefore if the navigation property entities need to be obtained, their Id’s can passed into a service/mapping layer function which will retrieve the entities from then database, map them to DTOs and return the collection. Is this an acceptable way of doing things?

I am new to this area so some of my terminology might not be totally correct but hopefully you’ll understand what I'm getting at. If you need me to clarify or provide additional detail on anything, please let me know.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can load the DTOs using a projection:

```
var paymentDtos = context.Payments
    .Where(p => p.Amount >= 1000m) // just an example filter
    .Select(p => new PaymentDto
    {
        ID = p.ID,
        PaidOn = p.PaidOn,
        Amount = p.Amount,
        Reference = p.Reference,
        PaymentMechanismId = p.PaymentMechanism.ID,
        OrderIds = p.Orders.Select(o => o.ID)
    })
    .ToList();
```

You have to declare the `OrderIds` in the dto as `IEnumerable<int>` though, not as `ICollection<int>` to make this compile.

I'm not sure if this key collection is really useful. If you want to load the orders later you could do it in a separate service method just based on the `ID` of the `Payment`, like so:

```
public IEnumerable<OrderDto> GetPaymentOrders(int paymentID)
{
    return context.Payments
        .Where(p => p.ID == paymentID)
        .Select(p => p.Orders.Select(o => new OrderDto
        {
            ID = o.ID,
            //etc. mapping of more Order properties
        }))
        .SingleOrDefault();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I appreciate your time. I would give you an up vote but I don’t have enough rep!

How does this projection example differ from a mapping library like AutoMapper?

I know exactly what you mean about the key collections, but it’s a way of keeping a reference to entity relationships. I suppose it’s not always necessary but it could prove useful for some DTOs.

Comment: @ChrisWhite: Using AutoMapper would force you to load the `Payment` entity including all `Orders` first from the DB (with all columns of order), then apply AutoMapper which would ignore most of the loaded properties because your collection in the dto only contains an `int`. This might be a lot of query overhead. The projection above is executed completely in the database and returns only the columns requested in the projection.

Answer (score 2):

I'm usually using Automapper for this kind of scenario. I would create a Dto class form my main entity and also Dto's for my navigation property entities, then let Automapper do the mapping automatically, without having to write the mapping code manually.

```
public class PaymentDto
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public DateTime? PaidOn { get; set; }
    public decimal Amount { get; set; }
    public string Reference { get; set; }

    //Navigation Properties
    public virtual PaymentMechanismDto PaymentMechanism { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<OrderDto> Orders { get; set; }
}

public class PaymentMechanismDto
{
//properties
}

public class OrderDto
{
//properties
}


public class MappingProfile : Profile
{
        public MappingProfile()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap< Payment, PaymentDto >();
            Mapper.CreateMap< PaymentMechanism, PaymentMechanismDto >();
            Mapper.CreateMap< Order, OrderDto >();
        }
}
```

Comment: How does this answer the question ?

Comment: @AymenDaoudi, it shows a way of how to use AutoMapper - which will map those properties automatically, without the need of manual mapping...